# Best way to re-encrypt a load of gpg encrypted files?

Tags: pgp

My question is, what is the best and easiest way to re-encrypt a load files which are currently encrypted to my *old* and *compromised* gpg sub-keys?

To expand upon this:

- I had gpg sub-keys which were used to encrypt some files.
- These sub keys were subsequently compromised.
- I issued new sub-keys.
- Now I'd like to re-encrypt those files to the new sub-keys.

I could write a shell script to do this, but I thought I would ask, as it seems like a common operation which I would have thought to be built in to gpg. I can't see anything relevant in the manual.

Thanks

Comment: Decrypt the files, after that process is done, encrypt the files again.